# ASP.NET MVC - The model item passed into the dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 buttons that I want to redirect to the other view with different model.
So I have a table and above, there are 2 buttons.

So I have this current code in my view

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
      <input type="button" value="Create Item" class="btn btn-primary"
         onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CreateItem", "Home")';return false;" />

      <input type="button" value="Create Records" class="btn btn-primary"
         onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CreateRecords", "Home")';return false;" />
 <div>
```

The first button or input type is working. Because the current view and the `CreateItem` have the same model which is:

```
 @model MyModel.Jobs.Web.Library.Doman.Item
```

But my 2nd input type has different model which has CreateRecords Action is:

```
 @model MyModel.Jobs.Web.Library.Domain.Records
```

So it throws me an error that is `System.InvalidOeprationException`. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Show us the CreateRecords action method present in your HomeController